# Can't use more than 2 cores with microsoft R Open

Tags: r, performance, multicore, microsoft-r

I recently installed Microsoft R Open but this message appears at startup of R:

"Multithreaded BLAS/LAPACK libraries detected. Using 2 cores for math algorithms."

on a MAC it's supposed to start using the 4 cores without any additional set up.

How can i change this to 3 or 4 cores?

Thank you

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_(Retina)), current MacBooks only have two physical cores.

Answer (score 0):

A very common way to setup multicore processing in RRO is to use the method `setMKLthreads()` out of the Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL). However, to the best of my knowledge, there is no OSX-compatible MKL version, yet (see [here](https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/multithread/) for more information).

Another way to achieve multicore processing on OSX would be to use `mcapply()` out of the `parallel`, which works similar to the base-R `lapply()` (see the package's documentation [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf)).

However, before you dig into this matter, I suggest to check if you really have a CPU with more than 2 physical cores. For instance, there are Intel i5 processors with both 2 and 4 physical cores dependent of the model. CPUs with only 2 physical cores, can then simulate a higher number of virtual cores. Since such i5 CPUs are frequently built into laptops, I think that this could be case if you are using a MacBook.

See also this SO question for further information: [Virtual core vs Physical core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264735/virtual-core-vs-physical-core)

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i can't find the setMKLthreads() function... not even in the cran help

Comment: setMKLthreads() is no base R function, but part of the MRAN package. See here for instance: https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/multithread/

Comment: Maybe you have to download and install the Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL) separately.

Comment: I'm on a MAC, that function only works for windows and linux.